# How i can use the wcf service in Visual Studio 2010 and fetch data from database in the json format?

Tags: json, wcf

I am confused. How can I use WCF with a database to show results in json format? 
How i can use wcf service in Visual Studio 2010 and fetch data from the database and get the result in json format?

Comment: WCF Data Services are a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [WCF Web HTTP Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412169(v=vs.110).aspx) is for - making content available at non-SOAP endpoints.  Here's a [helpful writeup](http://www.visualstuart.net/blog2/2011/11/anatomy-of-a-simple-rest-service/) on how to write a simple service returning JSON, written by another SO user, [@VisualStuart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1019277/visual-stuart).

Of note is the endpoint configuration in the web.config, which specifies the data format to be returned:

```
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name=""
                      defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```